# Insert a specific number of rows into a table based on values in a column in another table

Tags: excel, vba

I am a bit useless when it comes to excel VBA. I've got a problem that I need to solve where I have two tables on two separate worksheets in excel.

Table 1 on sheet1 looks like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzjd1.png) (picture attached)

What I need to achieve is to copy the values from the first 4 columns in table 1 and paste it into table 2 an "x" number of times in table2. "x" is defined by the corresponding value in the count column in table1.

The resulting table2 on sheet2 should look something similar to this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqvr8.png): (picture attached)

I would really appreciate if someone could show me how to achieve this with a vba macro.

Thanks a lot!

-shawn

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post up your code to show where the error lies.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to learn how to create Macros is to use the Record Macro function. It will produce the code of what you do within the workbook, however, in this instance you require loops so it is more complex.

The below code will achieve what you are looking for. I added in comments to explain what each line does.

```
Sub copyRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                      'Turn off ScreenUpdating so you won't see all the
                                                        'actions happen in real time

    Dim count As Integer                                'Declare variables
    Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastRow2 As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")                      'Set worksheet values
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ws1.Activate                                        'Sheet1 needs to be active to perform next step
    lastRow1 = ws1.Range("A50").End(xlUp).row           'Identify last row in table to know data size

    For i = 2 To lastRow1                               'For the number of rows in table, perform the following
        count = ws1.Range("F" & i).Value                'Set 'count' variable, number of times to paste row
        ws1.Activate                                    'Sheet2 needs to be active to perform next step
        ws1.Range(Range("A" & i), Range("D" & i)).Copy  'Copy data you want to transfer

        ws2.Activate
        lastRow2 = ws2.Range("A50").End(xlUp).row       'Identify last row in table
        lastRow2 = lastRow2 + 1                         'Want to paste data to NEXT row

        For j = lastRow2 To lastRow2 + count - 1        'Paste the data the number of times indicated
            ws2.Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial
        Next j
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True                       'Turn back on ScreenUpdating to see updated sheet

End Sub
```